# How do I draw a swirl in silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, drawing

By a swirl I mean starting at a central point a single line running in a circle with an increasing radius.

Comment: A spiral? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Archimedean_spiral.svg

Comment: Yes, like that, only different colors & thicknesses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a PathListBox. Here are some links on how to use the control. The last one deals specifically with a spiral.

http://www.uxpassion.com/2010/06/silverlight-4-tutorial-how-to-pathlistbox-sample-data-blend-4/

http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/SilverlightTV/Silverlight-TV-25-No-More-Boxes-Exploring-the-PathListBox/

http://www.reflectionit.nl/Blog/PermaLinka06af01a-09d6-46b8-a080-0069688c9363.aspx

Comment: Umm... yikes?  How many list items will be needed to draw the __line__ as specified in the question.  This would be a seriously heavy control simply to draw a line.

Comment: Can you not just specify the height/width and BG color? You don't need to put anything in it, but you easily could if the the need arrose; which is why I suggested it.

Comment: Looks that that was wrong... I wonder if you can add a solid color brush to to draw the line?

Comment: I deleted the text and in Blend changed the value of the Spiral's stroke to a solid color brush and it worked like a charm. Nothing in the actual control at all. Using the source from that final link: <local:Spiral x:Name="spiral"
                          UseLayoutRounding="False"
                          Spirals="{Binding Value, ElementName=sliderSpirals}" StrokeLineJoin="Round" StrokeThickness="10"  Opacity="0.5" Stroke="Green" />